# SCRIPT5: Access is denied for IE while requesting JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I want to retrieve json data using ajax request in javascript. SO i wrote a reusable code like the following.

```
function ajaxRequest() {
    var req;

    this.ajax = function(params, url) {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }
        req.open("POST", url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log('state\t' + req.readyState);
            return req.responseText;
        };
        req.send(params);

    }


}
```

How to retrieve data without changing Settings->Internet Options->Security->Custom Level and change security settings under "Miscellaneous" set "Access data sources across domains" to Enable.

For rest all browsers except IE its not working.

Comment: Why the `jQuery` tag?

Comment: Yes its cross domain

Comment: `var ajaxcall = new ajaxRequest();
 var BUYOnline_Json = ajaxcall.ajax(credentials, url);` this is how to call the function